# Game with username entry using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've downloaded a sample snake game from this github and I am desperately trying to modify the code to have an additional username entry window which then displays the username as the game is being played. I'd also hoping to code a leaderboard once I have the current issue sorted out.

My problem is that while the game itself works great as soon as I added the additional code to open the username entry window at the start the window dimension are applied to the game window as well.

Can anyone point out the likely blindingly obvious thing I'm missing here? My code is everything after the comment line.

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import messagebox

MOVE_INCREMENT = 20
MOVES_PER_SECOND = 15
GAME_SPEED = 1000 // MOVES_PER_SECOND

def StartGame():
    class Snake(tk.Canvas):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(
                width=600, height=620, background="black", highlightthickness=0
            )

            self.snake_positions = [(100, 100), (80, 100), (60, 100)]
            self.food_position = self.set_new_food_position()
            self.direction = "Right"

            self.score = 0

            self.load_assets()
            self.create_objects()

            self.bind_all("<Key>", self.on_key_press)

            self.pack()

            self.after(GAME_SPEED, self.perform_actions)

        def load_assets(self):
            try:
                self.snake_body_image = Image.open("./assets/snake.png")
                self.snake_body = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.snake_body_image)

                self.food_image = Image.open("./assets/food.png")
                self.food = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.food_image)
            except IOError as error:
                print(error)
                root.destroy()

        def create_objects(self):
            self.create_text(
                45, 12, text=f"Score: {self.score}", tag="score", fill="#fff", font=(10)
            )
            self.create_text(
                150, 12, text=f"Username: {username}", tag="username", fill="#fff", font=(10)
            )
            for x_position, y_position in self.snake_positions:
                self.create_image(
                    x_position, y_position, image=self.snake_body, tag="snake"
                )

            self.create_image(*self.food_position, image=self.food, tag="food")
            self.create_rectangle(7, 27, 593, 613, outline="#525d69")

        def check_collisions(self):
            head_x_position, head_y_position = self.snake_positions[0]

            return (
                    head_x_position in (0, 600)
                    or head_y_position in (20, 620)
                    or (head_x_position, head_y_position) in self.snake_positions[1:]
            )

        def check_food_collision(self):
            if self.snake_positions[0] == self.food_position:
                self.score += 1
                self.snake_positions.append(self.snake_positions[-1])

                self.create_image(
                    *self.snake_positions[-1], image=self.snake_body, tag="snake"
                )

                self.food_position = self.set_new_food_position()
                self.coords(self.find_withtag("food"), *self.food_position)

                score = self.find_withtag("score")
                self.itemconfigure(score, text=f"Score: {self.score}", tag="score")

        def end_game(self):
            self.delete(tk.ALL)
            self.create_text(
                self.winfo_width() / 2,
                self.winfo_height() / 2,
                text=f"Game over! You scored {self.score}!",
                fill="#fff",
                font=("", 10)
            )

        def move_snake(self):
            head_x_position, head_y_position = self.snake_positions[0]

            if self.direction == "Left":
                new_head_position = (head_x_position - MOVE_INCREMENT, head_y_position)
            elif self.direction == "Right":
                new_head_position = (head_x_position + MOVE_INCREMENT, head_y_position)
            elif self.direction == "Down":
                new_head_position = (head_x_position, head_y_position + MOVE_INCREMENT)
            elif self.direction == "Up":
                new_head_position = (head_x_position, head_y_position - MOVE_INCREMENT)

            self.snake_positions = [new_head_position] + self.snake_positions[:-1]

            for segment, position in zip(self.find_withtag("snake"), self.snake_positions):
                self.coords(segment, position)

        def on_key_press(self, e):
            new_direction = e.keysym

            all_directions = ("Up", "Down", "Left", "Right")
            opposites = ({"Up", "Down"}, {"Left", "Right"})

            if (
                    new_direction in all_directions
                    and {new_direction, self.direction} not in opposites
            ):
                self.direction = new_direction

        def perform_actions(self):
            if self.check_collisions():
                self.end_game()

            self.check_food_collision()
            self.move_snake()

            self.after(GAME_SPEED, self.perform_actions)

        def set_new_food_position(self):
            while True:
                x_position = randint(1, 29) * MOVE_INCREMENT
                y_position = randint(3, 30) * MOVE_INCREMENT
                food_position = (x_position, y_position)

                if food_position not in self.snake_positions:
                    return food_position

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Snake")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.tk.call("tk", "scaling", 4.0)

    board = Snake()

    root.mainloop()

# My code
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Snake game")
window.geometry('250x120')
Usern_label= tk.Label(window, text="Username: ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
Usern_label.place(x=10, y=10)
UsernInput = tk.Text(window, bg='White', bd=5, width=15, height=1)
UsernInput.pack
UsernInput.place(x=90, y=10)
username = UsernInput.get("1.0", "end-1c")
if len(username) > 8:
    messagebox.showwarning("Invalid username", "Please enter a valid username")

usern_button = tk.Button(window, text='Start Game', bd='5', command=StartGame)
usern_button.place(x=20, y=75)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problems is just copying the snake code and putting it in a function. You should take the `Snake` class out of the function. You should only have one instance of `Tk`, the root window. Therefore this needs to be created first. I've used `.withdraw()` to hide it until we need it. Then I've used `Toplevel` to create another window. This is like `Tk` but doesn't cause problems. Your current user validation does not work as you get and check the value of `UsernInput` immediately after creating it. Therefore it will always pass as the length of an empty string is less than 8. Instead you need to do the validation in the `StartGame` function. I've replaced the `Text` with an `Entry` because whilst `Text` would work fine, `Entry` is much more well suited to what you need (a single line of text).
When the user presses the button it calls `StartGame`. This validates the input and if it's valid it destroys the username window and shows the root, then does the same setup stuff as before. Although it isn't necessary in this case it's always a good idea to pass a parent widget to every child. In this case the snake canvas will automatically go to the root window but in your original code this is what caused the window size to be wrong as it automatically went in the username window. I've done this by adding the `parent` parameter to `Snake` and passing `root`. Assuming the `Snake` code all works fine this code should all work. If you want to use the value of username in `Snake` then you'll want to pass it as a parameter by changing it to `def __init__(self, parent, username):`. Then after adding something like `self.username = username` you can use it anywhere in the class.

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import messagebox

MOVE_INCREMENT = 20
MOVES_PER_SECOND = 15
GAME_SPEED = 1000 // MOVES_PER_SECOND

class Snake(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(
            parent, width=600, height=620, background="black", highlightthickness=0
        )
        # Rest of the Snake class code goes here

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Snake")
root.withdraw() # Hide root window for now

def StartGame():
    # Do the validation after the user has pressed the button
    # The input has no value if you call it immediately after
    username = UsernInput.get() # The get is easier with an Entry
    if len(username) > 8:
        messagebox.showwarning("Invalid username", "Please enter a valid username")
        window.focus() # Go back to the window after showing the warning
    else:
        window.destroy() # Get rid of the username input
        root.deiconify() # Show the root window again
        root.tk.call("tk", "scaling", 4.0)
        root.resizable(False, False)
        board = Snake(root)

window = tk.Toplevel() # Don't use multiple Tk instances
window.title("Snake game")
window.geometry('250x120')
Usern_label= tk.Label(window, text="Username: ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
Usern_label.place(x=10, y=10)
# It makes more sense to use an entry for what you are doing
UsernInput = tk.Entry(window, bg='White', bd=5, width=15)
UsernInput.place(x=90, y=10)

usern_button = tk.Button(window, text='Start Game', bd='5', command=StartGame)
usern_button.place(x=20, y=75)    

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is really very much appreciated, thank you! My experience with tkinter isn't extensive at all and I've only really managed to create small programs with really basic data entry. This works perfectly though, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)